# Files come back from deletion

Tags: shell-script, filesystems, rm, bcache

I have an script that does this:

```
 rm -rf "$test_dir" && sync && mkdir -p "$test_dir"
 unzip -qq "$zip" -d "$test_dir"
 # compile and run some stuff, diff some files...
 evince "$pdf" 2>/dev/null  # $pdf is a path inside the mentioned folder $test_dir
 echo "[Next]..."
 read
 # then it goes to the next zip, and do the same again.
```

- Let's call a zip file `A.zip`, and the next (in the list of zip files) `B.zip`.
- Each zip file comes with two text files, and a pdf.

## The problem:

When the extraction folder was already deleted, and re-created, and it is the turn of B.zip, I cat a text file, and open the pdf in evince. Evince shows the correct pdf from `B.zip` for one or two seconds.

After that, evince reloads the document, and shows the pdf that came from `A.zip`.

If I go and manually open the pdf again, it is effectively the one that came in `A.zip` instead of the one in `B.zip` (so evince is just opening the new file).

If I manually cat the text file again, the content is not the one of the last cat registered in the terminal (the one in `B.zip`), but the content of the text file of `A.zip`

## Suspicions:

I am suspecting that somehow, the folder itself (or its content) is coming back from deletion.

## Fix attempts:

Previously, I deleted the content of "$test_dir", but not the directory itself. The problem showed very often. Then I decided to delete the folder and re-`mkdir` it. This seemed to solve it. But now I am seeing the problem again.

I tried adding a `sync` command right after `rm -rf` so that goes into disk. The problem persists.

I tried `sleep` for a second after deletion. The problem persists.

## What I have checked:

I have seen several similar questions on the web, but all of them involve some other process, docker, or something else. The folder I am using is just a directory in my home. There is no process running anything special on it, except my script ([update] there was one actually, please see the answer)

I have checked, and I am not unzipping anything anywhere else in the script.

Comment: what do you mean by correspond? You mean that the text files are still the old ones? Was it ever the new ones? It shows you the the new files first, but then suddenly you have old files? To break this down, could you try checking the content of the text files and see if and when you get the new content and if and when it changes? Perhaps something in your`#some stuff` goes on to unzip the old zip as well? Does this also happen when you manually empty your folder and unzip the new file?

Comment: I mean that the new files get in the folder, I can actually cat a text file (as part of the `# some stuff`, and open the pdf with evince. But after a second or two, evince (I guess detects a change in the file, and) reloads the pdf, showing now the old file. If I go and manually cat the text file, it is not the new file anymore. I will try to come up with a minimum (non) working example. Thanks a lot for your comments and time. I will add some more details to the question.

Comment: One thing you can be pretty much assured of - files don't "come back" from deletion, except maybe if you have `rm` aliased to something (e.g., something that tries to provide a "recycle bin" type function instead of deleting files outright).  It's basically never necessary for a non-admin to run `sync` for any reason.  It is also not necessary to do `sleep` to wait for a filesystem operation to complete (from a user space perspective) - by the time your `unlink()` system call returns, the operation is done.

Comment: What I would try to do is manually track through the operations performed by the switch, line by line, and perform every operation the script would perform.  Manually simulate every line of code.  You might also consider posting the actual script you're working with (rather than a fragment of pseudocode) if it's small enough.

Comment: I actually know zombies are not real. It was just a desperate (and quite silly) attempt to kill a fly with a bomb. I tried to strip out the script, to provide a minimum non-working example, but on doing that I got rid of the bug... So now I know it is somewhere in the `# some stuff` as you mentioned... I will post the solution once I find it. Thanks again for accompanying me in rationalizing the problem.

Comment: In addition to the minimal example, you can also try running `inotifywait -m -r  $test_dir` (or the dir above perhaps) in another terminal. This will log all the "file operations" and should show you when something is changed again.

Comment: If your provided script is accurate, then the part that is changing it back must be executing in background (and finishing after evince opens). If it was done synchronously, you'd already have the old files when launching `evince`. Also: how do you launch the script? Perhaps you're unintentionally running more than one at a time?

Comment: Currently you include a set of commands that does not help the readers. Your problem is about the result of `evince $pdf` and we have no idea how you set this variable. Can you provide a full example to see if anyone of us could reproduce this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the responsible! it is the MegaSync application. It is running in the background, and somehow, while syncing all, it brings back the just deleted files. I close it, and problem solved.